# Simplifying a difficult trigonometric sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

As [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J0wgYX0JY0) shows,

$$\tan \left( \frac{3 \pi}{11} \right) + 4 \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi}{11} \right) = \sqrt{11} .$$

The direct and obvious methods for *Mathematica* to find this solution do not work:

```
Simplify[Tan[(3 \[Pi])/11]+ 4 Sin[(2 \[Pi])/11]]
```

or

```
TrigReduce[Tan[(3 \[Pi])/11] + 4 Sin[(2 \[Pi])/11]]
```

and the obvious application of `FullSimplify`, `TrigExpand`, and so on.

Is there any way to get *Mathematica* to find this reduction without having to impose clever "human knowledge"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Tan[(3 π)/11] + 4 Sin[(2 π)/11] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify
```

> `Sqrt[11]`

Comment: Oh gee.  How nice.  And quick.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$).  And what about the negative value?

Comment: `Tan[(3 π)/11] + 4 Sin[(2 π)/11] // N` equal to 3.31662. It is a positive number.

Comment: But the video found $\pm \sqrt{11}$.  Anyway, good enough.  Again, thanks.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork:  If you watch the last bit of the video (starting around 25:00), the presenter points out that since $3\pi/11$ is in the first quadrant, the quantity on the left-hand side must be positive.  So the video's final answer is $+\sqrt{11}$ only.

Comment: Also `Tan[(3*Pi)/11] + 4*Sin[(2*Pi)/11] // RootReduce`